# ASP.Net Identity running multiple queries on every request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

ASP.Net Identity is executing the queries below on every request. I have not changed any of the Identity code that was gen'd when my MVC project was created. My `Startup.Auth.cs` code is below.

Note that `validateInterval` is set to `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)`. Also note that cookie expiration is being explicitly set (`ExpireTimeSpan`) is set to `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)`. I found [a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45205085/asp-net-identity-executes-database-query-on-every-page-request-when-logged-in) whose answer indicated that `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)` should be sufficient to prevent ASP.Net Identity from reaching out to the DB on every request.

What am I missing here?

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
public partial class Startup
{
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
 {
  // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
  app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
  app.CreatePerOwinContext < ApplicationUserManager > (ApplicationUserManager.Create);
  app.CreatePerOwinContext < ApplicationSignInManager > (ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

  // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
  // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
  // Configure the sign in cookie
  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
  {
   AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
     // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
     // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
     OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator
      .OnValidateIdentity < ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser > (
       validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
       regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)),
    }
    SlidingExpiration = true,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
  });
  app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

  // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
  app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

  // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
  // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
  // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
  app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
 }
}
```

**Queries being executed on each request (standard ASP.Net Identity queries)**

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Extent1].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
    [Extent1].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
    [Extent1].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
    [Extent1].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
    [Extent1].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
    [Extent1].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
    [Extent1].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
    [Extent1].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
    [Extent1].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
    [Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName]
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p0',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=N'[ID]'

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent1].[ClaimType] AS [ClaimType], 
    [Extent1].[ClaimValue] AS [ClaimValue]
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'[ID]'

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[LoginProvider] AS [LoginProvider], 
    [Extent1].[ProviderKey] AS [ProviderKey], 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId]
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'[ID]'

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent1].[RoleId] AS [RoleId]
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'[ID]'
```

**EDIT**

I **did** make one change that I forgot to mention. We moved our Identity-related tables to a SQL DB. Changes below:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    // Changed connection string name
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MaestroConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: a) Do your users have any value in `SecurityStamp` field? b) Does the cookie actually change value on every request? c) What happens if you remove (just to test) code for `OnValidateIdentity` and don't assign anything there?

Comment: @trailmax, Sorry for the delay. Yes, values are present in the SecurityStamp field. The 3 cookies being set, `_RequestVerificationToken`, `.AspNet.ApplicationCookie`, and `ASP.Net_SessionId` all have an immediate expiration set. I don't get it.

Comment: Sounds like your `SecurityStampValidator` is playing up. Try comment out the code that executes it and see what happens.

Comment: @trailmax, I gave it a shot. No effect. Thanks though.

Comment: In that case I'd start debugging and have SQL profiler in another window. And then line by line watch when these SQL statements come up to figure out offending code. Then go from there.

Comment: @trailmax, I want to reiterate that I've not made any changes to the generated Asp.Net Identity code (expect to test). I also have another site that exhibits the same behavior. It almost seems like this is intentional - I just need to know why, and how to turn it off.

Comment: That's strange because I don't see that in my systems (I maintain a few). I'll go and try with the default Identity template.

Comment: I've created a new solution from the template and out of the box these queries are only executed on login or when the security stamp is invalidated (30 minutes after login by default). Also cookies are set to expire as "Session".

Comment: So something in your solution messes up with the cookies and Identity is forced to recreate the cookies on every request hence you see these requests to your DB.

Comment: @trailmax, I can't tell you how much I appreciate your help. Based on your comments, I went back and reviewed the code to confirm that I hadn't changed anything and **I did change one thing**. We moved our Identity-related tables to a SQL DB, so I changed the `ApplicationDbContext` base connection name. See edit above. Thoughts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163896/discussion-between-james-hill-and-trailmax).

Comment: I'm thinking this issue is not caused by Identity, but Identity suffers. Any changes to `web.config` or `global.asax.cs` that might affect cookies?

Comment: I think at this point you need to create minimal reproducable example and publish it somewhere.

Comment: Alternatively you can put breakpoint inside "regenerateIdentity" callback to see if it's related to security stamp or not, and also implement custom UserManager and put breakpoints there, so see the callstack when your queries happen.

Comment: @JamesHill do you have `<authentication>` tag in your web.config by any chance?

Comment: Hi, @Alisson, I do - `<authentication mode="None" />`. Forms auth is also being removed `<system.webServer><modules> <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, this one made me feel a bit foolish. After stepping through the code and noticing that `regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))` was being called properly and not repeatedly, I did some further digging.

In the nav menu partial view, I found this line of code:

```
<a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">@("@" + 
            ApplicationUser.CurrentUser.Email.Split('@')[0])</a>
```

Executing that code on every page load resulted in the 4 queries above being run. *headdesk*.

Comment: You said *The 3 cookies being set, `_RequestVerificationToken`,  `AspNet.ApplicationCookie`, and `ASP.Net_SessionId` all have an immediate expiration set*. Is this still happening?

Comment: @Alisson, the answer is yes, it's still happening. It's next on my list, although on the face of it, it doesn't seem to be affecting anything.